# Regex - How can I select the text between some HTML tags right after a specific tag?

Tags: regex

```
<dt class="prd_name">                            <!-- 1st line -->
<strong>4 ChitoLite Chitosan 780mg</strong>      <!-- 2nd line -->
                                                 <!-- 3rd line (empty) -->
                                                 <!-- 4th line (empty) -->
                    </dt>                        <!-- 5th line -->
```

Hi.
I have lots of similar HTML files.

I'd like to select only the text between the `<strong>` tags above using the regular expressions.

Of course, there are lots of `<strong>` tags.

What I want is **4 ChitoLite Chitosan 780mg** between the strong tags right after`<dt class="prd_name">`.

How can I do that?
I use the latest UltraEdit and Notepad++.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

This is my regex:

```
^(?s)<dt class="prd_name">(.*?)(?=</strong>)  // This one includes <dt class="prd_name"> and <strong> tags.

^(?s)(?<=<dt class="prd_name">.)(.*?)(?=</strong>) // This one doesn't work.
```

Comment: It means all the text between <strong></strong> right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gm` regex flags with the following regex pattern:

```
^<dt\s+class="prd_name">\s*<strong>\K.*?(?=<\/strong>)
```

https://regex101.com/r/fakRAE/1

Comment: Wow, it works great! Thank you so much! I have never seen \K. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to solve your query with regular expression str.matchAll() function.

I consider that there is always a tag is written in a qualified way means "".

```js
const txt =
  '<dt class="prd_name"><strong>**4 -1ChitoLite Chitosan 780mg**</strong></dt><dt class="prd_name"><strong>**4 0ChitoLite Chitosan 780mg**</strong></dt><dt class="prd_name"><strong>**4 1ChitoLite Chitosan 780mg**</strong></dt><dt class="prd_name"><strong>**4 ChitoLite Chitosan 780mg**</strong></dt><dt class="prd_name"><strong>**4 2ChitoLite Chitosan 780mg**</strong></dt><dt class="prd_name"><strong>**4 ChitoLite Chitosan 780mg**</strong></dt><dt class="prd_name"><strong>**4 3ChitoLite Chitosan 780mg**</strong></dt><dt class="prd_name"><strong>**4 ChitoLite Chitosan 780mg**</strong></dt><dt class="prd_name"><strong>**4 3ChitoLite Chitosan 780mg**</strong></dt><dt class="prd_name"><strong>**4 ChitoLite Chitosan 780mg**</strong></dt><dt class="prd_name"><strong>**4 4ChitoLite Chitosan 780mg**</strong></dt><dt class="prd_name"><strong>**4 ChitoLite Chitosan 780mg**</strong></dt><dt class="prd_name"><strong>**4 4ChitoLite Chitosan 780mg**</strong></dt><dt class="prd_name"><strong>**4 ChitoLite Chitosan 780mg**</strong></dt>';
const regExp = /<strong>(.*?)<\/strong>/gi;
const matchAll = [...txt.matchAll(regExp)];
console.log("total length:",matchAll.length);
console.log(matchAll);
```